# Как пользоваться уже сгенерированной нейросетью в python (библиотека keras) и не генерировать (обучать) её заново?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Допустим я написал и обучил нейросеть. Далее я хочу поэкспериментировать с ней, поработать, проверить, поиграться, но поскольку выполнение строк кода в питоне происходит сверху вниз, то при запуске скрипта вместо старой нс генерируется и обучается как бы уже новая нейронка. Процесс обучения часто бывает очень долгим и поэтому создавать и обучать новую нейросеть не совсем целесообразно.
Как сделать так чтобы я работал уже со своей уже готовой и обученной в первый раз нейронкой, а не генерировал каждый раз новую при каждом новом запуске скрипта?

Comment: Save and load Keras models: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize

Comment: @AlexF спасибо!